# A circle of diameter $410$mm is pitched at $30^\circ$ to the horizontal axis. What are the dimensions of its projection onto the horizontal plane?

Tags: trigonometry

I’ve searched the net but haven’t found what I am looking for.

> I have a circle 410mm diameter. If it was pitched at $30^\circ$ to the horizontal axis. What are the dimensions of its projection onto the horizontal plane?

Cheers in advance,

James

Comment: Did you draw the diagram?

Comment: Are you asking, what are the dimensions of the projection onto the horizontal plane?

Comment: Yes Gerry. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view the tilted circle from above, it will appear to be an ellipse with major axis $410$ and minor axis $410\sqrt3/2$.

Comment: Thanks for that Gerry. Worked out perfectly. I’m an apprentice builder and had to put a piece of fire retardant cement board around the top of a vertical flue that was going through a sloping (30 degree) roof. I thought there would be an online calculator for something like this but couldn’t find one. Excuse my ignorance but where are the best references to calculate future occurrences? Thanks again, James

Comment: You just multiply the diameter by the cosine of the angle of the tilt. By the way, if my answer is what you wanted, you have the option of "accepting" it by clicking in the check mark next to it.